# Pandas: Simple time series with a quantity and error

Tags: python, pandas, series

I'm struggling to find a suitable way of using pandas to hold a quantities and 1-sigma array as a `pd.Series` `data` attribute. Currently I pass a class a `pd.Series` instance and manipulate it using properties, etc.:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class TimeSeriesHandler:

    def __init__(self, time_series: pd.Series):
        self._time_series = time_series
        self.sigmas = np.zeros(self.number_of_timestamps)

    @property
    def timestamps(self) -> np.array:
        return self._time_series.index.values

    @property
    def number_of_timestamps(self) -> np.array:
        return self.timestamps.shape[0]
```

... and then use it as follows:

```
time_series = pd.Series(data=[3,2,3,2], index=[1,2,3,4])
time_series_handler = TimeSeriesHandler(time_series)
```

which represents the quantities that I'm interested in. But each of these quantities have a 1-sigma error of say, `sigmas = [1,2,1,3]`.

**Are there any suggestions on how I would manage this, please?** Is it a good idea to have a separate time series instance for `sigmas` -- this would mean unnecessarily duplicating the `index` value (or the `timestamps`).

Thanks for any help here.

Comment: You have duplicate `timestamps`  prop in your class

Comment: @Mirodil Thanks -- fixed.